# Python Firebase replace the auto-generated Key

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was adding some data to Firebase with Python and I want to use the MD5 strings I generated as the unique index for each record. 
The auto-generated key in Firebase looks like "-KgMvzKKxVgj4RKN-3x5". Is it possible to replace its value with Python? I know how to do it with Javascript though. Please help... Thanks in advance!

```
f = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com')
f.post('meeting/',
    {
     "MD5index":MD5String,
     "title": title, 
     "date": date,
     "time": time,
     "location": location
     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is. Just use `put` instead of `post`:

```
f = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com')
f.put('meeting/mymeetingkey',
    {
     "MD5index":MD5String,
     "title": title, 
     "date": date,
     "time": time,
     "location": location
     })
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your solution. It works! But in my case, "mymeetingkey" is a string variable. How can I add its value after 'meeting/'?

Comment: I think I know how... Thanks again for your help